# Getting segmentation error(code dumped in c++

Tags: c++

What is the problem encounter here? I'm so confused? 
The program should display a deck of shuffled cards.

I'm new to coding so I don't get it...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// names of ranks.
static const char *ranks[] ={"Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, 
                              Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King"};

// name of suites
static const char *suits[] ={"Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts"};

void print_card(int n)
{
    cout << ranks[n % 13] << " of " << suits[n / 13] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    vector<int> deck;

    // Prime, shuffle, dump
    for (int i=0; i<52; deck[i++]=i)
    {
        for_each(deck.begin(), deck.end(), print_card);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error(segmentation) and I don't know what it is :(

Comment: Using a debugger shows you the exact code line of the segfault, from which you then could deduce where the error lies.

Answer (score 4):

```
static const char *ranks[] ={"Ace, Two, ..., King"};
```

This is an array of size *one,* with the single element being the entire string, meaning accessing `ranks[<anything other than zero>]` is undefined behaviour.

What you need is an array of *distinct* strings, such as:

```
static const char *ranks[] ={"Ace", "Two", ..., "King"};
```

Ditto for the `suits` array.

---

You're also ill-advised to reference elements in a vector that do not yet exist, such as your `deck[i++]=i` when `deck` is empty.

To set *existing* elements, you can use that method (though it doesn't bounds check like `vector::at()` so beginners should probably be using that).

To *append* elements to the back of the vector, you can use `vector::push_back()`.

---

However, if you're going to become a C++ coder, you should embrace the language *fully,* including getting away from basic types when user defined types provide much more protection and expressiveness.

You can generate a `Card` class with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Card {
public:
    enum Rank { Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight,
        Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, EndRank };
    enum Suit { Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, EndSuit };

    explicit Card(Rank rank = Ace, Suit suit = Spades)
        : m_rank(rank), m_suit(suit) {}

    std::string ToString() const {
        return m_rankLookup[m_rank] + " of " + m_suitLookup[m_suit];
    }

private:
    const Rank m_rank;
    const Suit m_suit;

    static const std::vector<std::string> m_rankLookup;
    static const std::vector<std::string> m_suitLookup;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Card& me) {
        return os << me.ToString();
    }
};

const std::vector<std::string> Card::m_rankLookup { "Ace", "Two", "Three",
    "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack",
    "Queen", "King" };
const std::vector<std::string> Card::m_suitLookup { "Spades", "Clubs",
    "Diamonds", "Hearts" };
```

You can then build on that with a `Deck` class, along the lines of:

```
class Deck {
public:
    explicit Deck(unsigned numDecks = 1) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < numDecks; ++i) {
            for (auto suit = Card::Spades;
                suit != Card::EndSuit;
                ++(*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&suit)))
            {
                for (auto rank = Card::Ace;
                    rank != Card::EndRank;
                    ++(*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&rank)))
                {
                    m_deck.push_back(Card(rank, suit));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::string ToString() const {
        if (m_deck.size() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << m_deck[0];
        for (unsigned i = 1; i < m_deck.size(); ++i) {
            ss << ", " << m_deck[i];
        }
        return ss.str();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Card> m_deck;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Deck& me) {
        return os << me.ToString();
    }
};
```

From there, it's a matter of just using the classes as needed, comfortable in the knowledge that C++ will type-check things far more thorougly that if you had used raw integers.

And you simply add functions to do any other processing, such as getting a random card from the deck, or putting it back.

A test harness I used for those classes is:

```
int main() {
    Deck deck;
    std::cout << "[" << deck << "]\n";
}
```

and the output I got was (reformatted for readability):

```
[Ace of Spades, Two of Spades, Three of Spades, Four of Spades,
 Five of Spades, Six of Spades, Seven of Spades, Eight of Spades,
 Nine of Spades, Ten of Spades, Jack of Spades, Queen of Spades,
 King of Spades, Ace of Clubs, Two of Clubs, Three of Clubs,
 Four of Clubs, Five of Clubs, Six of Clubs, Seven of Clubs,
 Eight of Clubs, Nine of Clubs, Ten of Clubs, Jack of Clubs,
 Queen of Clubs, King of Clubs, Ace of Diamonds, Two of Diamonds,
 Three of Diamonds, Four of Diamonds, Five of Diamonds,
 Six of Diamonds, Seven of Diamonds, Eight of Diamonds,
 Nine of Diamonds, Ten of Diamonds, Jack of Diamonds,
 Queen of Diamonds, King of Diamonds, Ace of Hearts, Two of Hearts,
 Three of Hearts, Four of Hearts, Five of Hearts, Six of Hearts,
 Seven of Hearts, Eight of Hearts, Nine of Hearts, Ten of Hearts,
 Jack of Hearts, Queen of Hearts, King of Hearts]
```

Comment: I am sure those are just the formatting errors when pasting code.

Comment: Using  std::vector<std::string> makes programming easier, as no need to worry about native pointer.

Comment: Oops! True xD, I forget about the elements inside the arrays, now I understand how the vector int works. Thank you!

Comment: Btw I forget to include <ctime> in order to make srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); to work

Answer (score 3):

When you create the `deck` object using

```
vector<int> deck;
```

it is an empty vector. Using `deck[i++]` on such an object is not correct. You can create an object with the required size using

```
vector<int> deck(52);
```

Since the size is known at compile time, it will be better to use `std::array`.

```
std::array<int, 52> deck;
```

Answer (score 0):

core happened because deck[0] is NULL when looping

Can be like this

```
    for (int i=0; i<52; i++)
    {
       deck.push_back(i);
    }
    for_each(deck.begin(), deck.end(), print_card);
```

and the string arr

```
    static const char *ranks[] ={"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    static const char *suits[] ={"Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your deck doesn't have any elements, you cannot loop over it in this manner.

```
vector<int> deck;

// Prime, shuffle, dump
for (int i=0; i<52; deck[i++]=i)
{      
  for_each(deck.begin(), deck.end(), print_card);
}
```

Either call `resize(52)` on it after the declaration or directly call the constructor `deck(52)` which places 52 empty elements in it.